# Distributing cards between group of $4$ people

Tags: combinatorics

Four people named Julia, Tony, Wayne and Joe are playing a card game. A standard pack of 52 cards is dealt out, 13 cards being given to each player.
a. Find the probability that the cards dealt to Julia and Wayne include all thirteen spades.
b. Find the probability that the cards dealt to Julia and Wayne include at least one complete suit (e.g. 13 spades)

I can't understand why my method for the two parts is incorrect.
This is what I did:
Let Julia and Wayne have the 13 spades. They require 13 more cards in total.
So we can do this in $\binom{52-13}{13} = \binom{39}{13}$ ways.

The total number of hands will be $52!$ (... since all 52 cards are distributed, then arrange the hands)
So probability is $\binom{39}{13}/52!$.

For part b,
Define $S_i := \{ \text{ways of having Julia and Wayne having complete suite $i$}\}$.
Then we have to compute
$$ |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_4| = |S_1| + \ldots + |S_4| - (|S_1 \cap S_2| \cap \ldots \cap |S_3 \cap S_4|).$$
(the other terms are zero since their total cards is $26$).

I'm  not sure if this is the correct way to go, as I calculate
$|S_i| = \binom{39}{13}$ and $|S_i \cap S_j| = ???$ (I'm not sure how to calculate this)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In part $a)$ you did not consider that there are many possibilities how the spades are distributed

Comment: The solution says that the answer is $\binom{39}{13} / \binom{52}{26}$ so it seems that they have a different number of possibilities

Comment: The given solution is correct. There are $\binom{52}{26}$ possibilities for the cards Tony and Joe receive and $\binom{39}{26}=\binom{39}{13}$ possibilities for Tony and Joe to receive no spades.

Comment: I'm unsure the reasoning for those numbers.  
Especially, I'm unsure in the total amount of possibilities. This is the explanation given for total number of possibilities:  
We separate into two hands, Hand 1 (Julia and Wayne) and Hand 2 (Tony and Joe). The total number of Hands 1 and 2 is $\binom{52}{26}\binom{26}{26}$. I get this I think, but why is this valid?  
By the same reasoning, can't we split into two hands Hand X (Julia, Wayne, Tony) and Hand Y (Joe)  
to get a result of $\binom{52}{39}\binom{13}{13}$?

Comment: In part $b)$, you have to consider that Julia and Wayne could receive, for example, all hearts AND all spades.

Comment: The point is that we only need the number of possibilities for Tony and Joe because for each such possibilitity, we have the same number of possibilities for Julia and Wayne. This is a simplification for the calculation. But if we do that, we have to divide by the number of possibilities for Tony and Joe and not by the total number of possibilities.

Comment: We have the same ratio because the total number of possibilities is the number of possibilities for Tony and Joe multiplied with the number of possibilities for Julia and Wayne. Therefore, to calculate the probability, we can make this simplification. Without this trick, it is more difficult to get the correct answer.

Comment: Also be careful concerning the total number of distributions. Since the order (in each hand) does not matter, the number of hands is not $52!$, but $\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why did you divide by $(13!)^4$? I can't think why

Comment: Also, for your part b) comment, I thought that I would have accounted for it in my working, with the $|S_1 \cap S_2$ for example (although, I couldn't think how to compute it)

Comment: The $52!$ appears if the order matters for all cards. But the order of the $13$ cards for each player doesn't matter. So, $13!$ arrangements lead to the same result, and this for every hand. For $b)$, multiply the probability of $a)$ with $4$, then subtract the probability that Julia and Wayne receive all spades and hearts (this is $\frac{1}{\binom{52}{26}}$) ,multiplied with $6$ (because we have $6$ possible suit-pairs).